# Boost regex expression capture

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

My goal is to capture an integer using boost::regex_search.

```
#define BOOST_REGEX_MATCH_EXTRA

#include <boost\regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string tests[4] = {
    "SomeString #222",
    "SomeString #1",
    "SomeString #42",
    "SomeString #-1"
  };

  boost::regex rgx("#(-?[0-9]+)$");

  boost::smatch match;

  for(int i=0;i< 4; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "Test " << i << std::endl;

    boost::regex_search(tests[i], match, rgx, boost::match_extra);

    for(int j=0; j< match.size(); ++j)
    {
      std::string match_string;
      match_string.assign(match[j].first, match[j].second);
      std::cout << "    Match " << j << ": " << match_string << std::endl;
    }
  }

  system("pause");
}
```

I notice that each regex search results in two matches. The first being the string matched, and the second is the capture in parenthesis.

```
Test 0
    Match 0: #222
    Match 1: 222
Test 1
    Match 0: #1
    Match 1: 1
Test 2
    Match 0: #42
    Match 1: 42
Test 3
    Match 0: #-1
    Match 1: -1
```

The documentation discourages use of BOOST_REGEX_MATCH_EXTRA unless needed. Is it required to capture a single match within parentheses, or is there another way?

Comment: Would be good if you could link to the specific part of the documentation that mentions that `BOOST_REGEX_MATCH_EXTRA`'s use is discouraged. There is another way, but I would discourage that other way much more than using parentheses (if performance is the reason)!

Comment: @Jerry "that other way" might well be much more performant. Did you profile it for the OP's situation?

Comment: @sehe The 'other' way (using regex alone) is *always* less performant, that's the trade between functionality and performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more speed, perhaps Boost Spirit could bring it, or other Boost Xpressive.

Both will generate code from expression templates. Meaning, among other things, that if you don't "absorb" any attribute values, no cost will be incurred.

### Boost Spirit:

This solution is header-only. It can probably be made more efficient, but here's a start:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string const tests[] = {
        "SomeString #222",
        "SomeString #1",
        "SomeString #42",
        "SomeString #-1"
    };

    for(auto& input : tests)
    {
        int value;
        auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());
        if (qi::phrase_parse(f, l,  // input iterators
                    qi::omit [ *~qi::char_('#') ] >> '#' >> qi::int_, // grammar
                    qi::space,      // skipper
                    value))         // output attribute
        {
            std::cout << "     Input '" << input << "' -> " << value << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cf9c8bb8e787fbd)**

### Boost Xpressive

```
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive_static.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace xp = boost::xpressive;

int main()
{
    std::string const tests[] = {
        "SomeString #222",
        "SomeString #1",
        "SomeString #42",
        "SomeString #-1"
    };

    for(auto& input : tests)
    {
        static xp::sregex rex = (xp::s1= -*xp::_) >> '#' >> (xp::s2= !xp::as_xpr('-') >> +xp::_d);

        xp::smatch what;

        if(xp::regex_match(input, what, rex))
        {
            std::cout << "Input '" << what[0] << " -> " << what[2] << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a11cb86cfd3d53f)** too.

I have a hunch that the Spirit solution is gonna be more performant, and close to what you want (because it parses a general grammar and parses it into your desired data-type directly).

Comment: Added Boost Xpressive solution, in addition to the Boost Spirit one.